# How to get value as a key in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a `var x` in JavaScript

```
var x = [{"id":"11","affiliate_id":"190","affiliate_percent":"0.2","read_only":"1"},{"id":"12","affiliate_id":"33","affiliate_percent":"0.1","read_only":"1"}];
```

and I want value:

```
var x = [{"190":"0.2"},{"33":"0.1"}];
```

Here `affiliate_id` value is key and `affiliate_percent` value is value.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: obviously ... so i am in need

Comment: That's a syntax error. Do you have/want a string or an array?

Comment: no, that's not obvious. At least your try is not visible in the question.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the value starts out as an array as well; edit the question if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Just try with:

```
var x = [
  {"id":"11","affiliate_id":"190","affiliate_percent":"0.2","read_only":"1"},
  {"id":"12","affiliate_id":"33","affiliate_percent":"0.1","read_only":"1"}
];

var output = [];
for (var key in x) {
  var item = {};
      item[x[key].affiliate_id] = x[key].affiliate_percent;
  output.push(item);
}
```

Output:

```
[{"190":"0.2"},{"33":"0.1"}]
```

Comment: its showing blank response.. as i tested in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @user3607000 Can you provide link to this jsfiddle ?

Answer (score -1):

If you were trying to create a new value key on the fly you could do this:

```
var obj={};

obj[affiliate_id] = ""[{"id":"11","affiliate_id":"190","affiliate_percent":"0.2","read_only":"1"},{"id":"12","affiliate_id":"33","affiliate_percent":"0.1","read_only":"1"}]";
```